# How to parse Excel (XLS) file in Javascript/HTML5

Tags: javascript, json, html, xls, filereader

I am able to read Excel file via `FileReader` but it outputs text as well as weird characters with it. I need to read `xls` file row-wise, read data in every column and convert it to JSON.

How to read xls file row by row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an excel file contents on client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382572/how-to-read-an-excel-file-contents-on-client-side)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: this does not answer the question. I need to read excel file row by row. Although I can read it using FileReader(HTML5) but still unable to browse rows.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

Below Function converts the Excel sheet (XLSX format) data to JSON. you can add promise to the function.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
var ExcelToJSON = function() {

  this.parseExcel = function(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = e.target.result;
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
        type: 'binary'
      });

      workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
        // Here is your object
        var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
        console.log(json_object);

      })

    };

    reader.onerror = function(ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    };

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  };
};
</script>
```

Below post has the code for XLS format [Excel to JSON javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782074/excel-to-json-javascript-code)

Comment: it crashes for larger excel files in chrome , any good solution for that?

Comment: May I know how bigger your file is?

Comment: I used a promise to load the excel file, then inserted it as an argument...Anyone else ran into the issue

"Failed to execute 'readAsBinaryString' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."?

Comment: Can you send fiddle link

Comment: e.target.result() should be e.target.result
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Comment: For me, i had to declare `jszip.js` script before `xlsx.js`.

Comment: This code works but with the changes of **@FlorinVîrdol** and **user227353**, the response should be modified

Comment: How can I assign json_object to public variable and access it outside the for loop?

Comment: Why does it throw "Uncaught ReferenceError: XLSX is not defined" this error?

Comment: hi, how do I ,  instead of console.log(json_object) , assign this json_object value to global variable to use it outside this callback function, just like utility function which takes xls as param and returns json object array

Comment: I like gifts as much as the next guy, but why the wrapper function?

Comment: Now, instead of 

`
let XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
        let json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
`
I used,

`
let XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
`
XL_row_object is a JSON object.

Answer (score 119):

Old question, but I should note that the general task of parsing XLS files from javascript is tedious and difficult but not impossible.

I have basic parsers implemented in pure JS:

- http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xls/ (XLS files, what you wanted)
- http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/ (XLSX/XLSM/XLSB files)

Both pages are HTML5 File API-driven XLS/XLSX parsers (you can drag-drop your file and it will print out the data in the cells in a comma-separated list).  You can also generate JSON objects (assuming the first row is a header row).

The test suite http://oss.sheetjs.com/ shows a version that uses XHR to get and parse files.

Comment: If you could add some sample code to the answer, it'd make it much better (also add a diaclaimer if you are the libraries leader).

Comment: I blogged about this http://psjinx.com/programming/2014/01/04/parsing-excel-workbooks-using-javascript/ :)

Comment: could we skip few top rows and columns of xlsx with JS-XLSX?

Answer (score 58):

## Upload an `excel file` here and you can get the data in `JSON` format in `console`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
  var ExcelToJSON = function() {

    this.parseExcel = function(file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
          type: 'binary'
        });
        workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
          // Here is your object
          var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
          var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
          console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
          jQuery('#xlx_json').val(json_object);
        })
      };

      reader.onerror = function(ex) {
        console.log(ex);
      };

      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input id="upload" type=file name="files[]">
</form>

<textarea class="form-control" rows=35 cols=120 id="xlx_json"></textarea>

<script>
  document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

This is a combination of the following `Stackoverflow` posts:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083658/4742733
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515846/4742733

Good Luck...

Answer (score 16):

This code can help you
Most of the time jszip.js is not working so include xlsx.full.min.js in your js code.

## Html Code

```
 <input type="file" id="file" ng-model="csvFile"  
    onchange="angular.element(this).scope().ExcelExport(event)"/>
```

## Javascript

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.10.8/xlsx.full.min.js">
</script>

$scope.ExcelExport= function (event) {


    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var fileData = reader.result;
        var wb = XLSX.read(fileData, {type : 'binary'});

        wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName){
        var rowObj =XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
        var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(rowObj);
        console.log(jsonObj)
        })
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
    };
```

Comment: What about If I want to upload images as well in excel sheet

Comment: i am able to read excel and csv files

Answer (score 14):

If you want the simplest and tiniest way of reading an *.xlsx file in a browser then this library might do:

https://catamphetamine.gitlab.io/read-excel-file/

```html
<input type="file" id="input" />
```

```js
import readXlsxFile from 'read-excel-file'

const input = document.getElementById('input')

input.addEventListener('change', () => {
  readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then((data) => {
    // `data` is an array of rows
    // each row being an array of cells.
  })
})
```

In the example above `data` is raw string data.
It can be parsed to JSON with a strict schema by passing `schema` argument. See API docs for an example of that.

API docs:
http://npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

Comment: Is there a way to read all values as strings? You mentioned that in the example above `data` is raw string data but I'm calling it exactly like that and I'm getting strings, booleans, numbers, and dates

Comment: It does parse numbers and booleans because that's how those're represented in the spreadsheet, i.e. in a spreadsheet those types of data are not stringified.

Answer (score 7):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
<script>
    var ExcelToJSON = function() {

      this.parseExcel = function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var data = e.target.result;
          var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
            type: 'binary'
          });
          workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            // Here is your object
            var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
            var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
            console.log(JSON.parse(json_object));
            jQuery( '#xlx_json' ).val( json_object );
          })
        };

        reader.onerror = function(ex) {
          console.log(ex);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
      };
  };

  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    var xl2json = new ExcelToJSON();
    xl2json.parseExcel(files[0]);
  }


 
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="upload" type=file  name="files[]">
</form>

    <textarea class="form-control" rows=35 cols=120 id="xlx_json"></textarea>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

    </script>
```

Answer (score 7):

Thank you for the answer above, I think the scope (of answers) is completed but I would like to add a "react way" for whoever using react.

**Create a file called importData.js:**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
export default class ImportData extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            excelData:{}
        }
    }
    excelToJson(reader){
        var fileData = reader.result;
        var wb = XLSX.read(fileData, {type : 'binary'});
        var data = {};
        wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName){
             var rowObj =XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
             var rowString = JSON.stringify(rowObj);
             data[sheetName] = rowString;
        });
        this.setState({excelData: data});
    }
    loadFileXLSX(event){
        var input = event.target;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = this.excelToJson.bind(this,reader);
        reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <input type="file" onChange={this.loadFileXLSX.bind(this)}/>
        );
    }
}
```

**Then you can use the component in the render method like:**

```
import ImportData from './importData.js';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class ParentComponent extends Component{
    render(){
        return (<ImportData/>);
    }
}
```

`<ImportData/>` would set the data to its own state, you can access Excel data in the "parent component" by following [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/passing-data-between-react-components-parent-children-siblings-a64f89e24ecf):

Comment: I think the tag in the return statement should be `<ImportData/>` instead of `<importData/>`. I am fairly new to React but I believe component names are always capitalized. In any case, that is the name used when importing in the example.

Answer (score 1):

**This is for react js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  const readExcel = (file) => {
    const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);

      fileReader.onload = (e) => {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;

        const wb = XLSX.read(bufferArray, { type: "buffer" });

        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[0];

        const ws = wb.Sheets[wsname];

        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);

        resolve(data);
      };

      fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });

    promise.then((d) => {
      setItems(d);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const file = e.target.files[0];
          readExcel(file);
        }}
      />

      <table class="table container">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Item</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {items.map((d) => (
            <tr key={d.Item}>
              <th>{d.Item}</th>
              <td>{d.Description}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
readExcelFile = async ( file ) =>
{

    const fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer( file );

    fileReader.onload = ( e ) =>
    {
        const bufferArray = e.target.result;

        const wb = XLSX.read( bufferArray, { type: "buffer" } );

        const wsname = wb.SheetNames[ 0 ];

        const ws = wb.Sheets[ wsname ];

        const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json( ws );
        console.log(data);
    };

};
            <input type="file" name="excelfile" id="excelfile"  readExcelFile(file)>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do it using CDN with plain javascript

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/read-excel-file@5.x/bundle/read-excel-file.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <h1>read-excel-file</h1>
</html>
<script>
    var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "file");
    document.body.appendChild(input)
    input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    readXlsxFile(input.files[0]).then(function(rows) {
        console.log(rows)
    })
})
</script>
```

Simplest way to it using plain javascript.

Comment: getting error called readXlsxFile not defined even after using the cdn on top like you did

Comment: This does work for me, but FYI: it only pulls the first sheet's data, but it can read other sheets: `readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: 2 }).then(function(rows) { ... }` or `readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: 'Sheet2' }).then(function(rows) { ... }`. See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file for docs.

It also calculates the results of any formulas, which is nice.

Answer (score 1):

In the FileReader API along with the XLSX library to convert an Excel file to JSON there's an issue with character encoding resulting in incorrect characters in the imported data. To address the character encoding issue, you need to ensure that you're handling the encoding correctly while reading the file and also while converting it to JSON. The FileReader API doesn't provide direct control over encoding. You can use Uint8Array() then parse the text from binary.

```
// you can import or use CDN to load the XLSX
import * as XLSX from "xlsx";

const excelToJson = (excelFile) => {
// this function expects file
  if (excelFile === null) {
    return [];
  }

  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(excelFile);

    reader.onload = (e) => {
      const arrayBuffer = e.target.result;

      // Parse arrayBuffer to binary string
      const data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      // const binaryString = data.reduce((acc, byte) => acc + String.fromCharCode(byte), '');

      // Use TextDecoder to convert binary string to proper text
      const text = new TextDecoder().decode(new Uint8Array(data));

      // parse excel to json
      const workbook = XLSX.read(text, { type: 'binary' });
      const worksheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetName];
      const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

      console.log(jsonData);

      resolve(jsonData);
    };
  });
};
```

You can use the function as below, where file is the file object as received while choosing file with html input.

```
excelToJson(file).then((rows) => {console.log(rows)})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ever wondering how to read a file from server this code might be helpful.

Restrictions :

1. File should be in the server (Local/Remote).
2. You will have to setup headers or have CORS google plugin.

```
<Head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.12.4/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
    /* set up XMLHttpRequest */


    // replace it with your file path in local server
    var url = "http://localhost/test.xlsx";

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onload = function(e) {
        var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

        /* convert data to binary string */
        var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);

        var arr = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) {
            arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
        }

        var bstr = arr.join("");

        var cfb = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

        cfb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName, index) {

            // Obtain The Current Row As CSV
            var fieldsObjs = XLS.utils.sheet_to_json(cfb.Sheets[sheetName]);

            fieldsObjs.map(function(field) {
                $("#my_file_output").append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + field.Fields + '">' + field.Fields + '<br>');
            });

        });
    }

    oReq.send();
    </script>
</body>
<div id="my_file_output">
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

include the xslx.js , xlsx.full.min.js , jszip.js

add a onchange event handler to the file input

```
function showDataExcel(event)
{
            var file = event.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            var excelData = [];
            reader.onload = function (event) {
                var data = event.target.result;
                var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                    type: 'binary'
                });

                workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                    // Here is your object
                    var XL_row_object = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);

                    for (var i = 0; i < XL_row_object.length; i++)
                    {
                        excelData.push(XL_row_object[i]["your column name"]);

                    }

                    var json_object = JSON.stringify(XL_row_object);
                    console.log(json_object);
                    alert(excelData);
                })

            };

            reader.onerror = function (ex) {
                console.log(ex);
            };

            reader.readAsBinaryString(file);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will work in reading XLSX file using Javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>

<script>

function handleFile(e)
{
    //Get the files from Upload control
    var files = e.target.files;
    var i, f;

    var title;
    var choice;

    //Loop through files
    for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function(e)
        {
            debugger;
            var data = e.target.result;

            var result;
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data,
            {
                type: 'binary'
            });

            var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
            var roa;
            sheet_name_list.forEach(function(y)
            {
                /* iterate through sheets */
                //Convert the cell value to Json
                roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                if (roa.length > 0)
                {
                    result = roa;
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#files').change(handleFile);
});

</script>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The weird characters you got from reading the Excel file from the `FileReader` API comes from the structure of the file that differs a lot from a text file.

So reading it as `text` with the `FileReader` API will give those weirds character as a result.

What you can do is to use the `FileReader` API to read it as a `binary string`.
At this point if you try to log that `binary string` you will also get weirds characters.

In order to get your file content you need to parse that `binary string` to extract the data it contains. This can be done quite easily using [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs).

```
import { read, writeFileXLSX, utils } from "https://cdn.sheetjs.com/xlsx-0.18.7/package/xlsx.mjs";

const workbook = read(data, {
       type:'binary',
});
```

`data` is the `binary string` resulting from reading an Excel file as a `binary string` with the `FileReader` API.

`workbook` is an object that contains all the data of your file.

The `workbook.Sheets` instruction will give you access to all the `sheets` that are in the file.

`workbook.Sheets.sheet1` will give you access to the content of the first `sheet` of the file.

All the related arrays are from the `{key:value}` type.

The content of a `sheet` accessed this way is a single dimension `object` `array` wich contains all the cells of the `sheet` starting from the first cell of the header to the last cell wich contains data.
 Each of those cells has a key like this `'A1'`, `'B250'`, `'J3'`

This array also have two more entries with those keys `'!margin'` and `'!ref'`:
`'!margin'` refers to cells margins so it may not represent any interest.
`'!ref'` is more interesting as it contains the plage of cells containing data  wich is a `string`
 like this `'A1:J215'` from it you could get the amount of lines or the char of the last column.

If you want more informations you could check the [SheetJS](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs) documentation and there is a more detailed example here : [How to read an excel file contents on client side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382572/how-to-read-an-excel-file-contents-on-client-side/72260638#72260638)

**Note :**
If you want to use this import statement in an `html` page you'll need to do it inside those scripts `tags` : `<script type="module" defer> ... </script>`

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/darkosphere/pen/yLvMYvY?editors=1111) where you can test this method. There's only the most basic method. There are some shorter ways to do the same by using the SheetJS `utils` functions to convert directly the `sheet` content to another format.

Answer (score -5):

XLS is a binary proprietary format used by Microsoft. Parsing XLS with server side languages is very difficult without using some specific library or Office Interop. Doing this with javascript is mission impossible. Thanks to the HTML5 File API you can read its binary contents but in order to parse and interpret it you will need to dive into the [specifications of the XLS format](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx). Starting from Office 2007, Microsoft embraced the [Open XML](http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx) file formats (`xslx` for Excel) which is a standard.

Comment: @ducktyped, I am not aware nor have seen any javascript code that reads a binary Excel file.

Comment: Mission impossible? I doubt it. If we can run the Linux kernel in client-side javascript, then it should be possible to parse a binary Excel file. It's just that no one to my knowledge has done it yet.

Comment: Here is the documentation for curious of ms xls structure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc313154%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Answer (score -5):

var excel=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var book=excel.Workbooks.Open(your_full_file_name_here.xls);
var sheet=book.Sheets.Item(1);
var value=sheet.Range("A1");

when you have the sheet. You could use VBA functions as you do in Excel.

Comment: this only works with "our dear friend" IE. And I need to use HTML5. I just need to browse actual text content row by row.