# Execl to an array of objects in Javascript

Tags: arrays, reactjs, excel, object

I have an excel file with data as below

```
Sl.No   Company Name    Designation Salary
n1      ABC     Sam     Architect   100
n2      ABC     Bill    Engineer    200
n3      ABC     Jill    HR          300
n4      XYZ     Bill    Engineer    250
n5      XYZ     Tom     Mechanic    150
```

I want to convert this to a array of a objects as below

```
arrayObject = [{'Sl.No':'n1', 'company':'ABC', 'Name':'Sam', 'Designation':'Architect','Salary':'100.},
{'Sl.No':'n2', 'company':'ABC', 'Name':'Bill', 'Designation':'Engineer','Salary':'200.},
{'Sl.No':'n3', 'company':'ABC', 'Name':'Jill', 'Designation':'HR','Salary':'300.},
{'Sl.No':'n4', 'company':'XYZ', 'Name':'Bill', 'Designation':'Engineer','Salary':'250.},
{'Sl.No':'n5', 'company':'XYZ', 'Name':'Tom', 'Designation':'Mechanic','Salary':'150.}]
```

I want this structure so that I can later filter items based on company, Designation, Salary etc.
If another structure is good for the purpose, I am open for that as well.

I tried sheet.js in the path https://oss.sheetjs.com/sheetjs/ & I get the output as below & I feel that is not useful for my purpose.

```
{
  "Tabelle1": [
    [
      "Sl.No",
      "Company",
      "Name",
      "Designation",
      "Salary"
    ],
    [
      "n1",
      "ABC",
      "Sam",
      "Architect",
      100
    ],
    [
      "n2",
      "ABC",
      "Bill",
      "Engineer",
      200
    ],
    [
      "n3",
      "ABC",
      "Jill",
      "HR",
      300
    ],
    [
      "n4",
      "XYZ",
      "Bill",
      "Engineer",
      250
    ],
    [
      "n5",
      "XYZ",
      "Tom",
      "Mechanic",
      150
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question in here [Excel to JSON javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782074/excel-to-json-javascript-code)

The answer that was useful for me was the answer from user7456320 (the code is copied below as well).

All that was needed was the XLSX library.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Excel to JSON Demo</title>
    <script src="xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        /* set up XMLHttpRequest */
        var url = "http://myclassbook.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Test.xlsx";
        var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        oReq.open("GET", url, true);
        oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

        oReq.onload = function(e) {
            var arraybuffer = oReq.response;

            /* convert data to binary string */
            var data = new Uint8Array(arraybuffer);
            var arr = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
            var bstr = arr.join("");

            /* Call XLSX */
            var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
                type: "binary"
            });

            /* DO SOMETHING WITH workbook HERE */
            var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            /* Get worksheet */
            var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];
            console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet, {
                raw: true
            }));
        }

        oReq.send();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```