# How to detect the file type if it's an excel file in JavaScript on the web?

Tags: javascript

I am using the [FileReader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API to read files on the browser, I want to render something on the screen conditionally based on the file the user uploads:

- JSON.
- CSV.
- Excel.

How can I detect if the file uploaded is an excel file? Do you use libraries for that or is there a genius way we can detect that blindly without going through all the chances?

Comment: btw I'm working with react, so I can use npm

Comment: Check if it isn't a JSON file and if it isn't a CSV file.

Comment: Generally one relies on the file extension. `.xlsx' would be Excel

Comment: Alternatively you can just try to parse the files as each type and if it fails you know it isn't of that type

Comment: @Codebling, okay good solutions, thanks. btw, you can't rely on the file extension, because if the user is on Linux he can store his files without an extension on his computer

Comment: You can also store your files without an extension on Windows. It's just common to keep the extensions, on both linux and Windows (source: I am a linux user).

Comment: If you don't have an extension on linux, the OS doesn't know what type the file is. You can manually run `file` command to detect the file type

Comment: @Normal Linux uses file extensions. Some file browsers will hide them. Double-check the actual filename with `ls` and you'll probably see they have extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Running out of space in comments, so I'll add an answer. Files will usually have an extension, on both Windows and Linux, but if you don't want to rely on that you can just try parsing the file in each of the formats to find the one that succeeds.

- **JSON** use `JSON.parse()`
- **Excel** see [this question for `.xlsx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-xls-file-in-javascript-html5) or [this one for `.xls`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782074/excel-to-json-javascript-code), or use [one of the many NPM packages](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=xls)
- **CSV** the format is pretty simple, but there are gotchas for commas in the values. Some of the libraries are pretty efficient at streaming large files, so probably worth [using an NPM package again](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=csv)