# How to read excel file from browser?

Tags: javascript, java, vba, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I want to validate some of the data of an excel file from browser.

I can achieve it by the following,

Save excel in temporary notes document and extract into server hard disk/ Shared path and I can validate the excel.

My question is,

Is there any way to read the excel data without saving in notes document/ Server hard disk?

For me saving into notes document is not a major concern, I do not want to keep the data on server hard disk/ any shared folder. So

Is there any way to read the excel data from notes attachment without extracting into server hard disk/ Shared folder?

**Note: I do not want to use any external library/third party tool for achieving this,**

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to move the validation / processing to the client-side. Then just submit the data if it is valid, or alternatively just submit the data you want to the server.

This SO Q&A has details of a javascript-based XLS parser:  [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)

Alternatively, if the Excel file is simply a CSV, you could use other javascript libraries to parse the file on the client-side.

The key is the [FileReader](http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader) object in javascript, which is available on Chrome, Firefox, and IE 10 and above, allows you to upload a file and read it in memory in JavaScript.

Comment: I guess that this also requires external javascript library and sad part is, some of our application is very old and compatible only on IE8.