# Upload and process a spreadsheet without storing it permanently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to provide an option to export data via a spreadsheet. I don't want to store it permanently (hence there's no need of storage services like S3). What would the most most efficient and scalable way of doing this? Where can I temporarily store this file while it is being processed? Here's what should happen:

1. List item
2. User uploads spreadsheet
3. My backend processes it and updates the DB
4. Discard the spreadsheet

My 2 requirements are efficiency and scalability.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you i would look for a way to parse the XLS/CSV on the front-end and sending JSON to your backend. This way you pass slow /intensive work to the client (scalability) and process only JSON on the server.

You can start here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083658/1540290

Comment: I thought of that, but wouldn't it take the client a very long time to process a large file - say 5MB?

Comment: @user1175969 well, I suppose you should test that out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a form with a file input to pick the xls file you want to process like this:

```
<input id="my_model_source" type="file" name="my_model[source]">
```

To process the xls you could use [roo gem](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo).

#### Option 1:

In some controller (where you are processing the file) you can receive the file like this: `params[:my_model][:source]`. This file will be an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` instance. This class has the instance method [`path`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html#method-i-path) that will give you a **temp file** to work with.

So, with roo gem, yo can read it like this:

```
xls = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(params[:my_model][:source].path, extension: :xlsx)
```

#### Option 2:

The option one will work if your importing process is not too heavy.
If indeed, is too heavy you can use [Active Job](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) to handle the processing in background.

If you choose Active Job, you:

- will lose the opportunity to use `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`'s `path` method. You will need to generate the temp file on your own. To achieve this you could use [`cp` command](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/fileutils/1.9.2/FileUtils%3acp) to copy the `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`'s `path` wherever you want. After use it you can deleted with [`rm` commnad](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-rm)
- will lose a real time response. To handle this you could use [Job Notifier gem](https://github.com/platanus/job_notifier)

I have tried to show roughly what paths you can take.