# how to count the excel record and show the alert message of total number of record uploaded in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to count the excel data and give an alert message in angularjs. Does anyone know how to write the code for counting record in angular service?

[image]

Comment: var uploadDataServiceFactory = {};
  uploadDataServiceFactory.uploadData = function(uploadDataDTO) {
   return $http.post(uploadDataURL, uploadDataDTO)
   .then(function(results) {
    console.log(results);
    //console.log($scope.story);
   
    $log.debug(results);
    return results.data;
   }, function() {
    $log.error("error");
    return [];
   });
  };

Answer (score 0):

External library exists to parse an xls file like : https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx.

I suggest to you to read this stack : [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)