# Use Html5 to read Excel file

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I need to read excel file data when upload the file .

Is there any way that can use html5 to read excel file data when file uploading in client side??

heard about

var reader = new FileReader();

any way that we can use this

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5

Comment: You can't use HTML5 to achieve this as it's a markup language, but with Javascript it can be achieved.
You mentioned "I need to read excel file data when upload the file", why should this be limited to the client side?

Comment: i'm using meteor and i want to upload and read excel file in client side @N15M0_jk

Comment: @mituw16 it's about file read

Comment: @sasy Did you look at the link I posted? It is a question asking literally the exact same thing as you. *How to read an excel file in javascript*

Comment: Hmmm ok, are you using this data on the front end and manipulating it in any way? @sasy

Comment: @mituw16 i figured how to read the excel file ,but i want to read excel file data when select the excel file (without upload it )

Comment: @N15M0_jk yes , i'm using that excel file data to update database

Comment: @sasy Right I'm following you now. From my knowledge you're going to have a difficult time because Excel files are Microsoft proprietary software, are you limited to using an Excel spreadsheet specifically?

Comment: @N15M0_jk yes.client wants to use excel file for the database update .
is it possible in javascript ??

Answer (score 0):

Referring to @mituw16 comment on the question, take a look at the following question:
[How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)

As a seperate response to work from, I would suggest using a plugin like:
https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
To iterate through the spreadsheet and save the information in your database.