# How to load XLS file into javascript using js-xls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, js-xlsx

I have a input type=file and I'm trying to have [js-xls](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xls) load it.

```
<input ngf-select ng-model="mypage.myfile" type="file" id="file_input" name="myfile" >
```

Here are three different ways I've tried to load the file in my controller:

```
var workbook = XLS.readFile(mypage.myfile);
```

It says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFileSync' of undefined
```

I also tried this:

```
var workbook = XLS.read(mypage.myfile, {type:"binary"});
```

And get:

```
TypeError: f.charCodeAt is not a function
```

And finally:

```
var workbook = XLS.read(mypage.myfile.toString(), {type:"binary"});
```

And get:

```
Error: Unsupported file 91
```

I verified each time that the mypage.myfile is actually there and what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this ended up being the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083658/13009

I changed the XLSX to XLS which I think will handle both.  I also removed the outer function, I'm not sure what it was doing, and added a callback to do the actual work.