# How to read an excel file using AJAX??

Tags: javascript, ajax, excel

I am working on a project where I need to extract data from an excel file stored on client side so than i can work on that data. is there any way to do it without using any other Javascript library??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)

Comment: As the file is provided on the client side, AJAX is not required.

Comment: Ok. so how do i extract data from it?? i want to use just pure Javascript and no other libraries

Answer (score 0):

you can make a simple ajax call and get the responseText

```js
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/", true);
request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
  if(request.readyState === 4)
  {
    var content = request.responseText;
    document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = content;
  }
}

request.send();
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: that's probably because excel uses a format you can't read. Try to save your file in csv, it will work :)

Comment: It did. thank you. So basically there isn't a way to read an excel file in the format which i actually wanted. right??

Comment: yeah, without using external library, you won't be able to read .xls files (and I'm not sure a lib exists for that :p)