# count rows in excel file in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, excel, codeigniter

I want to upload an Excel file in my codeigniter project. But before uploading I want to show number of records in the file. So I created a function in script and called the function in the onclick event of submit button. In the function I wrote the following code to count the rows

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var fil = $('#contactFile');
var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open(fil.value);
var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets(1);
var rows = excel_sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
alert(rows);
```

But it shows an error that is,

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
```

I think modern web browser's do not support `ActiveXObject`. But instead of this `ActiveXObject`, there may be some other methods in modern browsers. But after a long search I didn't get a solution. Someone please help me

Comment: ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser. So every other useragent will throw an error

Comment: I know. but how do I count the rows in other browsers

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5

Answer (score 0):

I using angular 6. I hope it can help you. My idea is counting rows in excel file after uploading file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLZCn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE22K.png)

```js
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
type AOA = any[][];

export class ETicketStep3Component implements OnInit {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }
  ...

    data: AOA = [];
  wopts: XLSX.WritingOptions = { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' };

  onFileChange(evt: any, output: UploadOutput) {
    /* wire up file reader */
    const target: DataTransfer = <DataTransfer>(evt.target);
    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cannot use multiple files');
    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      /* read workbook */
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });

      /* grab first sheet */
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];

      /* save data */
      this.data = <AOA>(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, { header: 1 }));
      console.log("The count in excel file: ",this.data.length)
    };
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }
}
```