# How can I read the xlsx-file using JS on client

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I can get some properties a xlsx-file such its name, size, type, but I can't read data of this file in base64-coding:

```
function onFilesSelect(e) {

    var files = e.target.files; // xlsx-file
    console.log(files[0]);

    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {    
        var file = files[i];

        var data = [file.name, file.type, file.size];
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (function (file, data) {
            return function (e) {
                console.log(e.target.result); 
            };
        })(file, data);

        var list = reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
        //var list = reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        //var list = reader.readAsText(file, 'utf-8');
        //var list = reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        console.log(list); // wrong data
    };
};
```

[image: screenshot of console]

I had used different metods readAsArrayBuffer(), readAsText(),  readAsDataURL() but I can't read the xlsx-data. 
I don't want use server side I'm trying use only client side (https://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/file-system/pub/FileSystem/)
Can somebody help me?

Comment: You could check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083658/344140

Comment: FYI, an .xlsx file is a zipped collection of XML files. Which also shows, the data dump starts with PK (signature bytes of a zip file)

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? [There's a ton of info out there on this](https://www.google.com/search?q=xls+reader+javascript&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab). SheetJS is a good one i've used in the past.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)

Comment: SheetJS use server-side on PC

Comment: I'm read a ton of info but I can't got solved my problem.

Comment: @PrinceOFF - I'm not sure where you saw serverside code for SheetJS but I've used it a number of times and I promise you, you don't need a server.

Comment: Result of usage of SheetJS:  http://s.csssr.ru/U5LQQCK7T/20180126195725.png

Comment: Can anybody help me?