# Create a web form I can paste excel rows/columns into

Tags: javascript, html, excel, forms, input

How do I create a web form that accepts input that would be copied and pasted from Excel? Basically, I have a table on my website I use for managing my project every now and then it makes sense to just copy and past a section from excel and paste it into the website. However standard form fields just put all the values inside one input.

Is there a way to set up a form with rows and columns that would accept values from Excel and parse it into the same structure in rows and columns to be updated on my website?

Comment: Probably. What have you tried so far? Do you have a [mcve] of those efforts?

Comment: You could try parsing an excel sheet into JSON, and adding it to the table. [This might help you out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5)