# Get username and password by calling Name in Javascript , returns multiple value

Tags: javascript, excel, automation

Let a Excel file with 3 columns

- **Name | ID   | Pass**
- Adam | id123 | pass123
- Helen | id234 | pass234
- ken | id567 | pass567

How to make a function that returns Id and Pass if I call by Name.

Ex:

1. If call Helen It will return Helen's Id and Pass from the excel.
2. If call ken It will return ken's Id and Pass from the excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the excel file into javascript first and then maybe come up with a JSON that looks like this:

```js
var data = {
  "Adam": {
        "id": id123,
        "pass": pass123
   },
  "Helen": {
        "id": id456,
        "pass": pass456
   }
}
```

The values can be now referenced as:

```js
var AdamId = data["Adam"]["id"]
var AdamPass = data["Adam"]["pass"]
```

See [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5) on how to read an excel file.