# Issue in Reading Excel (xlsx) File Data in JavaScript/SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to read a .xlsx file in my SAPUI5 application using `FileReader` api. The UI5 control that I am using to upload the file is `sap.ui.unified.FileUploader`
My requirement is to read the content of the Excel sheet and display its data in a table in my UI5 application.

For this, I create a `FileReader` instance and call its `.readAsBinaryString` or `.readAsText` method and pass my file to it.
When the content is read, inside the onload event, the content of the file is displayed in an unreadable format (refer below)
[image]

Am I missing something? Or is there a different way of reading Excel data?

Comment: check this, you may get some idea  [youtube reference link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1S0LOAkTak)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse Excel file in client side or server side. Excel files are not plain text. Old excel files (xls) can not parse without Excel, it has own binary format. But you can parse xlsx files, these are zipped multiple file which contains raw data, image and style files.

- You can use exsting js library for client parse, example post [How to parse Excel file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5).
- You can use [abap2xlsx](https://github.com/sapmentors/abap2xlsx) library for ABAP backend.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [mkysoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2847159/mkysoft)'s and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-file-in-javascript-html5) answer. I was able to read the .xlsx file content.

For this, I had to create two files `jszip.js` and `xlsx.js` in my project. I created a separate folder for them and mentioned the two files' locations in `sap.ui.define` section in my controller.

The two libraries are available at 
[CDNJS - JSZip](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js)[3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js) and
[CDNJS - XLSX](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js)[4](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js) locations.

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    .... //other libraries
    "projectnamespace/foldername/jszip",
    "projectnamespace/foldername/xlsx"
], function (Controller,...., jszip, xlsx)
```

And then, to read the `.xlsx` file I added the following code:

```
    var oFileUploader = sap.ui.getCore().byId("fileUploader"); // get the sap.ui.unified.FileUploader
    var file = oFileUploader.getFocusDomRef().files[0]; // get the file from the FileUploader control
    if (file && window.FileReader) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            var excelsheet = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: "binary"
            });
            excelsheet.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                var oExcelRow = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(excelsheet.Sheets[sheetName]); // this is the required data in Object format
                var sJSONData = JSON.stringify(oExcelRow); // this is the required data in String format
            });
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
```