# Read Excel File and Store it in array using javascript

Tags: javascript

Already i have created the the Browse button which is used to upload the excel file after that I need to read the uploaded file data and parse the data in array variable using javascript.
I have attached the script for input button to upload the excel file.

From this I need to read the uploaded excel file and store the data in some array varialble.

For this case I need some help.Please help me to find out the solution.'

`````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="Generator" content="EditPlus®">
  <meta name="Author" content="">
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">
  <title>mainobj</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="file" name="my_file" hidden="hidden"/>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
<input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />

 </body>
</html>
````
`````

Comment: See [how to parse excel in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-xls-file-in-javascript-html5)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=Read+Excel+File+and+Store+it+in+array+using+javascript+site:stackoverflow.com)***, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.