# How to parsing and get specific values from excel file?

Tags: javascript, excel, parsing, xls, exceljs

**In the excel document(*.xls), how to parsing and get specific values by javascript?**

1. Firstly, getting a specific number(per quantities in the product that red color) from a sentence in the "Name" or "Name2" field.
2. Calculate "Price" and value from "1" in the same row.
3. Finally, how to insert the calculation result from "2" to a new column in the same row?

> **Yellow and blue column is made to explain**

> **Yellow** column is expected calculation logic.

> **Blue** column is the expected value.

[image]

Comment: Are you in for a treat.  The Script Lab Add In is a great place to start.  You should read [Excel JavaScript API overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview?view=excel-js-preview) and research Excel Taskpane Add In for code examples.

Comment: @TinMan thanks, but I don't have and need Microsoft.

Comment: This may help: [How to parse Excel (XLS) file in Javascript/HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-xls-file-in-javascript-html5).  Parsing an Excel file is not a simple task. Good luck.