# How can I directly display a value from an excel cell?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a trigger button that, when pressed, will display a value from an excel cell in alert box or on the page.
below is all I could get, but it doesn't display anything on the page.

update: I managed to do this using ActiveX, but I don't want to use this library for some reasons. Do you have any idea how I could do it?

update code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.15.6/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Excel to HTML</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Press to show</p>
        <input type="button" onclick="ReadData(4, 2) ; msgprint()" value="Show" />
        <div id="div1">
            <script>
                function ReadData(cell, row) {
                    var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
                    var excel_file = excel.Workbooks.Open("mypah/myworkbook.xlsx");
                    var excel_sheet = excel.Worksheets("Sheet1");
                    var data = excel_sheet.Cells(cell, row).Value;
                    document.getElementById("div1").innerText = data;
                }
            </script>
        </div>
        <script>
            function msgprint() {
                alert(document.getElementById("div1").innerText);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code can work only in IE, and only if the used ActiveX is installed and registered, and is allowed to execute in Internet Options.

Comment: ... ok, do you know another method?

Comment: Why not to use the library you're loading?

Comment: Ok, i ll try it

Comment: What is the source of the Excel file and where is the file stored?

Comment: in C:// path on my pc

Comment: look here you may find what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238407/how-to-parse-excel-xls-file-in-javascript-html5

Comment: everything I found here is with an upload button and that's not what I want. I would like that after pressing the button, the file would be directly uploaded from a source predetermined by me.

Comment: You can't access visitor's local filesystem using JS on a web page, visitor must interactively browse the file for your code.