# Read Excel and Create Json Req

Tags: java, json, excel

I have an excel with some data, how do we create a json request reading that data from excel using java, i am almost new to json ,

> Excel :-  RID COID    IssD    ExpD    Desc    XValue  XSource 1   2   3   4   5   6   7

JSON :- ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean java or javascript? For java there exist a few libraries to read excel files. If it's javascript, then look at this here for the read part http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6382572/how-to-read-an-excel-file-contents-on-client-side

Comment: Yes i mean java, I had done a similar one for SOAP, but have no clue how to do it for JSON,I alos have the code to read excel file but after reading how to create a json request is what i have no idea .

Comment: What do you wish to do with the JSON request? Send the content to a remote URL or do you wish to accept JSON requests?

Comment: i need to create a json request after reading the excel and the send the content to remote url and fetch the response

Comment: Creating JSON requests contains three steps: 1) Create the JSON request Body, and 2) sending it via Http and finally 3) parse the JSON answer 1+3) can be done via some JSON java libraries (org.json.simple.XXX) for example, and 2) via apache commons HttpClient